# Can we identify Marketing cloud memberID using SSJS as we do in AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

Can we retrieve and identify Marketing cloud memberID as below using SSJS platform library as we do in AMPscript?

```
IF memberid == 7765150 THEN
        SET @de = 'QA_DE'
        SET @url = 'https://pub.s11.exacttarget.com/QA'
        SET @style = '20'
        SET @js = '9'
    ELSEIF memberid == 7287650 THEN
        SET @de = 'DE_SIT'
        SET @url = 'http://pub.s11.exacttarget.com/SIT'
        SET @style = '23'
        SET @js = '55'
    ELSE
        SET @de = 'ProdDE'
        SET @url = 'https://pub.s11.exacttarget.com/prod'
        SET @style = '232'
        SET @js = '113'
    ENDIF
```

Comment: How are visitors arriving to your CloudPage?

Comment: Via link which is in Marketing cloud email I wanted this so I can define Data extensions from differnt BUs ( Dev , QA , Prod) in one code so no need to modify code once we deploy in Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilise this function to access the MID in SSJS:

```javascript
var mid = Platform.Recipient.GetAttributeValue('memberid');
```

To be honest, I have not tested it in a Script Activity, but it works as expected in a Cloud Page.

Comment: Thanks @Lukas for your response , I will check as you suggest :)